# Find next or previous word on textview

Tags: android

I have a string `java` which is what im looking or finding inside my textview. If i search for that string, it highlights the word using that function below i've used and it's working fine. Now, what i'm after now is to go to the `next` or `previous` word which is equivalent to the string `java`. How can i achieve something like that?

Here's what i've tried so far:

```
    TextView details = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.details);
    details.setText(text.getDetails());

    //value of string to find
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
    String getText = text.getText().toString();

    changeTextView(details, getText);
```

function that highlights string in textview

```
    private void changeTextView(TextView tv, String target) {
      String bString = (String) tv.getText();
      int startSpan = 0, endSpan = 0;
      Spannable spanRange = new SpannableString(bString);

      while(true) {
        startSpan = bString.indexOf(target, endSpan);
             if(startSpan < 0) 
                   break;
             endSpan = startSpan + target.length();
             spanRange.setSpan(
                         new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                         startSpan,
                         endSpan,
                         Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      }
         tv.setText(spanRange);
    }
```

I want to achieve like this image here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage index of selected text. Increase this value by pressing next, and decrease, by pressing previous. And then choose span depends of selected index.

Add this click listeners to your buttons

```
    findViewById(R.id.next).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selected++;
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.previous).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selected--;
        }
    });
```

Change method call to this one

```
    selected = changeTextView(details, getText, selected);
```

And use this updated method

```
/**
 * Returns normalized value, if selected index out of bounds
 *
 * @param tv       textView to display search results
 * @param target   text to search
 * @param selected int selected index
 * @return normalized value of selected item or -1 if text not found
 */
private int changeTextView(TextView tv, String target, int selected) {
    if (selected < 0) {
        selected = 0;
    }
    String bString = tv.getText().toString();
    int startSpan = 0, endSpan = 0;
    Spannable spanRange = new SpannableString(bString);

    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (true) {
        startSpan = bString.indexOf(target, endSpan);
        endSpan = startSpan + target.length();

        boolean isLast = bString.indexOf(target, endSpan) < 0;
        if (startSpan < 0)
            break;

        ParcelableSpan span;
        if (currentIndex == selected || isLast && selected > currentIndex) {
            // selected span
            span = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            if (isLast && selected > currentIndex) {
                // normalize if selected out of bounds
                selected = currentIndex;
            }
        } else {
            // deselected span
            span = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
        }

        currentIndex++;
        spanRange.setSpan(
                span,
                startSpan,
                endSpan,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    tv.setText(spanRange);

    if (currentIndex == 0) {
        // text not found
        return -1;
    } else {
        return selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: clicking on the buttons doesn't seem to update it's stylespan

Comment: I forgot. You should add changeTextView call inside each click listener

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For setting highlighting use BackgroundColorSpan.

```
 int index=0;     
 TextView tv ;

 private void changeTextView(String target,boolean prev)
 {
     target = target.toLowerCase();      
     String bString = tv.getText().toString();         
     int startSpan = 0, endSpan = 0;
     Spannable spanRange = new SpannableString(bString);
     bString = bString.toLowerCase();

     if(prev)
     {                                   
         index -= target.length();             
         index -= 1;
         if(index <= -1)
             index = bString.length()-1;
         index = bString.lastIndexOf(target, index);
         if(index <= -1)             
             index = bString.lastIndexOf(target, bString.length()-1);                                
         index += target.length();          
     }           
     else
     {
         index = bString.indexOf(target, index);                 
         if(index == -1)
             index = bString.indexOf(target, 0);
         index += target.length();            
     }                             

     while(true) {
            startSpan = bString.indexOf(target, endSpan);
            if(startSpan < 0) 
                  break;
            endSpan = startSpan + target.length();
            if(index == endSpan)
             spanRange.setSpan(
                        new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE),
                        startSpan,
                        endSpan,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            else
               spanRange.setSpan(
                        new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW),
                        startSpan,
                        endSpan,
                        Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
     }
        tv.setText(spanRange);                  

 }
```

OnCreate method

```
 tv = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1));
 changeTextView("search_text",false);

    //Previous
    ((Button) findViewById(R.id.prev)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeTextView("find",true);
        }
    });

    //next
((Button) findViewById(R.id.next)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            changeTextView("find",false);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a tip, think over it, you can get your answer.

Store the contents of the **paragrapgh** in a String.

Initialize a variable `count` to 0 outside of your while loop.

Inside while loop keep incrementing the value of `count` variable by 1 if it is able to find the string which you are interested in, after that call another while loop where

```
while(count!=0)
{
      spanRange.setSpan(
                     new StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD),
                     startSpan,
                     endSpan,
                     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);//function which higlights the word
      count--;
}
```

This count variable will keep track of the string which have occured in the paragraph.

By this method, you are tracking all the words from the given Paragraph and highlighting only those Strings which you are interested in.