# How can I select a word specified in textView

Tags: android

I have some text in a `textView` and I want all phrases that are as the `Note` in my text select them and change the their color to the red color. How can I do this? Is there a method for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32778859/find-next-or-previous-word-on-textview/32780509#32780509

Comment: You can check answers in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612652/select-a-word-on-a-tap-in-textview-edittext).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
String text = "Some text in the text view.";
String searchText = "the";
int startPos = -1, endPos = -1;

if(text.toLowerCase().contains(searchText.toLowerCase())){
   startPos = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase());
   endPos = startPos + searchText.length();
   Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(text);
   if (startPos != -1){
      spanText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), startPos, endPos, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
      yourTextView.setText(spanText);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following to highlight all the "Note" words in your textview..
first set the word to change color:

```
String stringtoChange = "Note";
```

then change the color using the replaceAll method of the String class:

```
textToHighlight = textToHighlight.replaceAll(stringtoChange, "<font color='red'>" + stringtoChange + "</font>");
```

where textToHighlight is your textView text and finally set the edited text to the textView:

```
your textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textToHighlight));
```